# how to make only the item template invisible?

Tags: asp.net

I want to put a if statement in my code behind to make only the item template in my repeater invisible, can i do this?

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater_CategoryMenu">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div id="productCategory">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            hey
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The following code makes the whole repeater invisible not just the item template..

```
Repeater_CategoryMenu.Visible = false;
```

Comment: After 158 questions you should really know to tag properly. This is NOT classic ASP it's ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the `ItemDataBound` event, so first have this line in your `Page_Load`:

```
Repeater_CategoryMenu.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(Repeater_CategoryMenu_ItemDataBound);
```

Then such method:

```
void Repeater_CategoryMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null && (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        if (some_condition_here)
        {
            e.Item.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Bind the repeater to an empty collection **OR**
2. Make the controls inside the repeater invisible in OnDataBinding